# How to order child records by parent column using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('role.id')
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent')

class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('parent.id')
    name = db.Column(db.String())
```

I am trying to order child records by parent role_id:

```
child_recs = Child.query.order_by(?).all()
```

I tried by placing order_by attribute in db.relationship(), but it's not working.

```
children = db.relationship('Child', backref='parent', order_by='Parent.role_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the required results with the help of `sorted()`:

```
child_recs = Child.query.all()
ordered_child_recs = sorted(child_recs, key=lambda rec: rec.parent.role_id)
```